# Running Python from the command line doesn't find libraries

Tags: python, matplotlib, path, python-3.7

I know for a fact I have matplotlib installed (e.g, I can do the import using ipython) but I upgraded to python 3.7 earlier today and looks like I broke something:

```
> python plot_spectra.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot_spectra.py", line 3, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'


~ > which python
/Users/npr1/anaconda3/bin/python
~ > which python2
/usr/local/bin/python2
~ > which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
```

Suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Apparently you have at least 3 different python versions installed. When running `python plot_spectra.py` you run a version that does not have matplotlib installed.

Comment: You are running anaconda's distribution of Python, you probably installed matplotlib in one of the other two